# Boost Test register exception translator

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost-test

Does anybody know how to register my custom exception translator when using auto test cases in Boost.Test? I've found some examples (very few actually), but they do not show how to use this feature with auto test cases which are the biggest advantage of boost.test in my opinion. My example test suite:

```
    #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE StateMachineTest
    #define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

    #include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE (FirstTest);

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE (testBasic)
    {
            BOOST_CHECK (true);
    }

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END ();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I'm still using Boost 1.34.1)

Regardless of the `AUTO_TEST_CASE` feature, to register custom exception handlers you need to implement the `init_unit_test_suite` main function. (You do not need to register any of your auto tests there.)

All my unit tests projects use a ut_main.cpp file that contains (roughly) the following:
(This is in addition to all the other cpp files containing the actual auto tests.)

```
void translate_mfc_exception(CException* pMfcEx) {
  ...
  BOOST_ERROR(msg);
}
// ...
using namespace ::boost::unit_test;
test_suite* init_unit_test_suite(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  // Initialize global Handlers:
  unit_test_monitor.
    register_exception_translator<CException*>( &translate_mfc_exception );

  // Return dummy suite to make framework happy:
  test_suite* test = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "Empty Test Suite" );
  return test;
}
```

This should be all you need in addition to your auto test cases.

Comment: Note: You generally don't want to catch _pointers_ to exceptions, just the exception itself. So no `Exc*` in the translator arg / template parameter, just `Exc` will make you happy.

Comment: @ron - *Generally* yes, but read my source! It says `translate_MFC_exception` **MFC** Exceptions are thrown and caught *by pointer*, so yes, I need to catch those by pointer. Possibly it isn't the greatest example, but it's used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can register translator in global fixture

Comment: I found out how: call `boost::unit_test::unit_test_monitor.register_exception_translator<>()` from within the fixture.